# Able to Export a site but unable to import in another webapplication

Tags: deployment, export, import

Here I am using SharePoint 2013.

I exported site collection with no errors, but when trying to Import site onto different web application as a site, I got below error

> Verbose: List URL: /DeviceChannels [03/17/2014 11:35:02 PM] [ListItem]
>   [1_.000]   Error: The list item could not be added or updated because
>   duplicate values were found in the following field(s) in the list:
>   [Alias].

Comment: Is the Alias field a custom field of yours ? I would suggest to check the original data as it probably does contain a duplicate value. This is possible if the field was set to enforce unique values after it already contained duplicates.

Comment: /DeviceChannels is default list in SharePoint 2013. My value for Alias field is enforce unique values to no

Comment: The cause of the error is that you set the column as unique, so when SharePoint Import the list and this check failed. On the source side uncheck the unique enforcement then export and import.

Comment: Ow, I wasn't aware, sorry. Since this is an internal SP problem, I would try alternatives for exporting the Site Collection. What method did you use now ? Backup-SPSite ?

Comment: then how you trying to import, did you created a site collection before hand for import, if yes what template you used?

Comment: @CameronVerhelst I am using Import-SPWeb Command

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE I am using Import-SPWeb Command and I already created site with publishing template

Comment: Export/Import-SPWeb does not export a site collection but only an SPWeb. Are you running the import on an existing SPSite ? If you want to Export/Import an SPSite, use Backup-SPSite and Restore-SPSite instead.

Comment: @CameronVerhelst I am creating new web application on same server

Comment: i would recommend you this.. create a site collection on destination using the powershell but without mentioning any template then try to import it........New-SPSite http://<site name>/sites/test -OwnerAlias "DOMAIN\user"

Comment: In that case, I would try to import your backup under an existing site collection under the web application (create a new site collection there, than run the backup to the site's url).

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE I will try your solution let u know

Comment: Was there a fix? I have the same issue. I know WHY it's happening. It's happening because I'm moving a root level site collection into a subsite which has a root site collection with the deviceChannels library already present. The question is, how do you get around this? I've tried deleting DeviceChannels, but you can't. I've tried editing the value, but you can't. I've tried deleting the value.

Comment: I was able to get around that error by changing the destination's root site collection DeviceChannels library title and name in SP Designer. It was able to import without that error the next time.